# "Consolidation" algorithm name / implementation

Tags: string, algorithm

Not quite sure how to describe this, but I have a word game I like to play that I'd like to implement as a computer program.

The basic gist is that you look at the values of the letters (A=1..Z=26), and consolidate the letters into the fewest possible, and that are the closest possible to each other.

As an example:

```
s t a c k
```

Sum the values

```
19 + 20 + 1 + 3 + 11 = 54
```

Find the fewest number of letters:

```
ceil(54/26) = 3
```

Choose letters closest to each other

```
54/3 = 18
```

Letters to be displayed should be `rrr`.

That happens to be an easy example. What would it look like when you need to have, say, `rrs` (if your initial string was 'a stack' instead)?

Does this already have a name that I can lookup and implement?

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem boils down to this: given `n` and `k`, find numbers `r1`, `r2`, ..., `rk` such that `sum(r1 + r2 + ... + rk) = n` and `max(r1, r2, ..., rk) - min(r1, r2, ..., rk)` is as small as possible.

The solution is pick `r = floor(n / k)`, and set `n mod k` of the numbers to be `r + 1`, and the rest `r`.

For example, if `n = 55` and `k = 3` (your example), we have `floor(55/3) = 18` and `55 mod 3` is `1`, so the solution is `19, 18, 18`.

All that remains is converting between numbers and letters.

Comment: haven't yet coded this out, but want to verify it'll also give a condensed list like `ssttt` (if the total is 98)